# How to make EditText smaller than default?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I need to show a large number of EditText controls on a screen, each of which will only allow entering 0-2 digits. The default EditText size is too wide for me to show enough EditText controls on a screen, but I have been unable to figure out how to make them narrower. I have tried the following attributes in

**XML:**

```
android:maxLength="2"
android:layout_width="20dip"
android:maxWidth="20px"
android:ems="2"
android:maxEms="2"
```

So the question is: how can EditText be made smaller than default?

Comment: padding property to use and small the edit text in application

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this way instead, shows the difference. Use the layout_width with the specified width.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<EditText
    android:width="10dip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    android:maxLength="2"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: That actually looks about as wide as the default to me. How does it look if you have just two characters in the EditText?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean now. With no width specified, the whole width of the text is used for the default up to the width of the screen.

Comment: Ah, got it. My problem was that I had the controls in a table, and changing just one made no change. Once I changed them ALL I saw the changes.

Answer (score 4):

Hey once you try this,it may work.......
 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"

Answer (score 1):

In case you end up on this page to search how to achieve the same in Java code..

```
txtSample.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});
```

Answer (score 1):

When in a table, as you describe, android:layout_gravity="left" will collapse the EditText to to the stated size of the EditText